# V-S inversion: Gets my daughter a present

Tags: subject-verb-inversion

Recently got curious about V-S inversion. Heard and saw some of them from the lyrics of songs, daily conversations, et cetera, I want to know how it works. As inversion is generally used in writings, it occurs to me that it would be not so appropriate to use inversions in conversations. But the truth is that they are widely used and fairly understandable.

Here is the sentence which made me curious.

- Gets my daughter a present, I do . . . (Not sure the rest of it)

If this is idiomatic, how about these sentences below I just made and how can they work?

- Receives the boy the prize, everyone congratulates him.
- Brags my brother about his new phone, I want to hit him.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that the first sentence has subject verb agreement on 'get'?  The first sentence looks more to me like it involves what is usually called VP topicalization.  It involves moving the verb phrase (defined as the main verb, plus its dependents) to the beginning of the sentence.  This is usually done for some sort of rhetorical effect, and the VP usually has to be "old" information with respect to the discourse.  Some examples:

1. John said he would finish the project, and *finish the project* he did.
2. I'll tell him to get out of town, and *get out of town* he will.

Notice that you can only do this by leaving an auxiliary verb behind (i.e. in the place where the VP has moved from), and therefore the main verb must not bear tense or agreement.

3. *John said he would finish the project, and *finished the project* he.

This is why I'm suspicious that the first sentence you give has the 3rd person '–s' on 'get'.  It's more likely that the sentence is:

4. Get my daughter a present, I do

which means "I get my daughter a present", not "My daughter gets a present".

The sentences that you've tried to construct don't follow this pattern, and are as a result ungrammatical sentences in English.

In order to express the kind of thing that those sentences express, English uses some sort of gerund, often times with the preposition 'with', if the subject of the gerund is present.

5. The boy having received the prize, everyone congratulated him.
6. With my brother bragging about his phone so much, I really want to hit him.